# iOS accessibility - disable accessibility under custom view

Tags: ios, accessibility

I have custom view that can be half screen size.
It appears on top of user interface.
I want to disable accessibility for controls covered by this view.
And I also want to make controls on custom half screen view accessible.

Is it possible to do it?

PS I don't want to implement UIAccessibilityContainer protocol for custom view - because I want it's subviews to work accessible by default behavior.

Thank you.

UPDATE: is it posible to cancel accessibility touch?

Answer (score 4):

Swift:

```
view.isAccessibilityElement = false
```

Also you could hide all subviews:

```
view.accessibilityElementsHidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility can be disabled like this:

```
[aView setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that the view should never be seen by assistive technologies, the best way is to override `isAccessibilityElement` in your custom view and return `NO`.